# Centralizar H3 na section (Verticalmente e Horizontalmente)

Tags: html, css, css-centering

Estou com um problema de alinhar um `h3` no centro da `section`.
Já tentei de várias formas mas nada.

```css
.BlackSky {
  background-color: #1C1624;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.StarsSky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/star.png');
}

.StarsSky h3 {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<section class="BlackSky"> //Bacgkround
  <section class="StarsSky">
    <h3>Teste</h3>
  </section>
</section>
```

entretanto o `Teste` não fica alinhando corretamente.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Centralizar H3 na section](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294841/centralizar-h3-na-section)

Answer (score 1):

```css
section{
  background-color: #1C1624;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.StarsSky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/star.png');
}
h3{
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="BlackSky">
  <section class="StarsSky">
    <h3>TESTE</h3>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Tem outra pergunta idêntica em : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294841/centralizar-h3-na-section/294866#294866[