# Centralizar H3 na section

Tags: css

Estou tentando corrigir um erro no [meu site](http://givago.com.br/) de deixar o `h3` no centro da section, já tentei vários métodos, não sei se pode é erro ou outro.

o CSS é este:

```
.BlackSky{
  background-color: #1C1624;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.StarsSky{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/star.png');
}
.StarsSky h3{
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
```

e o HTML é este:

```
<section class="BlackSky">
  <section class="StarsSky">
    <h3>Givago Fritzen</h3>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta: [**Centralizar H3 na section (Verticalmente e Horizontalmente)**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294825) ... **aguarde alguém responder.**

Comment: Usuário fez duas vezes a mesma pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294825

Comment: Verdade, aconteceu pedir para confirmar o e-mail, e achei que não tinha ido, vou tentar corrigir isto. 
Obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 2):

Como responderam acima, você pode utilizar a propriedade do `flexbox`

Analisando seu site, acho que o seguinte código resultaria no desejado!

```
.StarsSkyContent {
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

A propriedade `height: 80vh` determina que esta section ocupará um tamanho de 80% da tela, e as demais propriedades são para determinar a posição do elemento na página!

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é apenas centralizar o `<h3>`, creio que pode ser resolvido com `display:flex` e `justify-content:center`, segue abaixo:

```css
.BlackSky{
  background-color: #1C1624;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.StarsSky{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/star.png');
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.StarsSky h3{
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
```

```html
<section class="BlackSky">
  <section class="StarsSky">
    <h3>Givago Fritzen</h3>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
section{
  background-color: #1C1624;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.StarsSky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/star.png');
}
h3{
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  text-align: center; 
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="BlackSky">
  <section class="StarsSky">
    <h3>Givago Fritzen</h3>
  </section>
</section>
```

pode usar :

```
.h3 {

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.
Obrigado.
(desculpe fazer responder duas vezes)

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar `margin: 0 auto;`. Se não der, tente deixar a **section** como flex!

Lembrando, margin pode ser utilizada de várias formas, dizendo quais lados da magin quer utilizar: `margin-left`, ou pode ser utilizada como `margin: 10px 10px;`Sendo o primeiro valor, o responsável pelo **top** e **bottom** e o segundo valor, responsável pela: **left** e **right**. Não sei se deu para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim.

```
<style>
 .text-center{ text-align: center; }
</style>

<h3 class="text-center"> texto exemplo </h3>
```